# AVPlayer volume fade in

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, fadein

I need to do volume fade in  at the beginning and resume of playing stream radio using AVPlayer. I found an example:

```
assert(_player.currentItem.tracks.firstObject);
AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters* fadeIn = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:_player.currentItem.tracks.firstObject];
[fadeIn setVolume:0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
[fadeIn setVolume:1 atTime:CMTimeMake(2, 1)];
NSMutableArray* paramsArray = [NSMutableArray new];
[paramsArray addObject:fadeIn];
AVMutableAudioMix* audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
audioMix.inputParameters = paramsArray;
_player.currentItem.audioMix = audioMix;
```

But in the real time I have crash in the first line  and IDE warning  "Incompatible pointer types sending 'AVPlayerItemTrack * _Nullable' to parameter of type 'AVAssetTrack * _Nullable'" in the second line.

I recently work with avplayer and needs help

Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

I have workaround use MPVolumeView

```
for (UIView *view in [volumeView subviews]){
        if (![view.class.description isEqualToString:@"MPVolumeSlider"]) {
            continue;
        }

        UISlider *volumeViewSlider = (UISlider *)view;
        // volume from 0 to 1 
        [volumeViewSlider setValue:volume animated:YES];
        [volumeViewSlider sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        break;
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank You. But I needs programmatically increase the volume from zero to 1 in a few seconds without user interaction

Comment: AVPlayer has property volume. Can you try to change it?

Comment: Yes...    _player.volume = _player.volume + 0.05;
    if(_player.volume == 1.) return;
    else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(soundFadeOut) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
    }

Comment: but the problem is that I can not find out when the stream really starts playing sound

Comment: AVPlayer has property rate try to listen it via KVO

Comment: Thank you very much